# I need to get the grepped output of a file to be a variable.

Tags: bash, perl, variables, grep

I'm just drawing blanks here

I have a file that's being called with a home variable and I need to grep the file and remove a line

```
$HOME = $ENV{HOME};
$servers="$HOME/path/file.conf"
```

So from this I need to grep the file and remove a line from it. 
If I'm at a prompt I would just do a grep -v servername but is there a way to do this by just modifying the $servers I'm only editing one part of the script but I need to remove a server from this list.

I was trying something like

```
 servers = $($HOME/path/file.conf |grep -v servername);
```

But my Perl isn't that good, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Any help would be lovely, thanks
CM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use linux grep :

```
 my $HOME = $ENV{HOME};
 my $servername='someserver.com';
 my @servers = qx(grep -v $servername $HOME/path/file.conf );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slurp the file into an array of lines then filter out the lines you don't want:

```
use File::Slurp;

my @lines = read_file("$HOME/path/file.conf");
@lines = grep { $_ !~ /servername/ } @lines;
```

Comment: I used Michael's answer above but thanks for responding, I'll definitely keep slurp in mind :-)